# React setState function form useStatehook

Tags: reactjs

As react setter function re-renders the app why it's waiting for the function to execute completely before rerendering

```
function handlePhone(num){
  setPhone(num)
console.log('hello')
console.log('hello')
console.log('hello')
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question and/or issue is. Are you asking why your calls to `console.log` happen before your component is rerendered?

Comment: yes, you got it that's my question

Comment: Why would you expect the behaviour to be different or is there something in particular you are trying to do that needs the component to re-render before the callback has completed? How would your callback function behave if the component was rendered and it was redefined during execution?

Answer (score 0):

React useState-setter functions are asynchronous. So when you call the function handlePhone, js is calling setPhone and moves on to the rest of your code.